# How To Properly Display My Inputted Variables On The Terminal Following Receiving The Input On C++

Tags: c++, string, variables, input, output

I'm trying to run a simple line of code here where I get three different integers provided by the user in the terminal under the CamelCased variable declarations: GuessA, GuessB, And GuessC.

```
int GuessA, GuessB, GuessC;
    std::cin >> GuessA;
    std::cin >> GuessB;
    std::cin >> GuessB;
    std::cout << "You entered: " << GuessA << GuessB << GuessC;
```

My output looks like this in the terminal

If I enter for example for my GuessA, GuessB, And GuessC Input:

```
1
2
3
```

My Output is::

```
you entered: 1313630328
```

Why is it not displaying:

```
123
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
std::cin >> GuessA;
std::cin >> GuessB;
std::cin >> GuessB;
```

with

```
std::cin >> GuessA >> GuessB >> GuessC;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check you fourth line:

```
std::cin >> GuessB;
```

Do you mean `GuessC` here?

---

Since you `cin >> GuessB` twice, `GuessB` now store the last value you input, `3`. And `GuessC` was uninitialized, which can have any value, which is why you are seeing `13630328` for it.

Answer (score 0):

variables in c ++ take random values ​​by default , in your code,you didn't set GuessC value, you

```
std::cin >> GuessA;
std::cin >> GuessB;
std::cin >> GuessB;/* you have set GuessB two times and forgot    GuessC */
```

by default, GuessC had the value 13630328, that is why you had this result :

```
you entered: 1313630328
```